# Getting "Bad Request" when using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am living in Denmark where we have the ability to pull all data regarding our power usage from the website [Eloverblik.dk](https://eloverblik.dk/welcome).

They have even provided a nice API, so you can make your own programs that pulls the data from their website:

https://api.eloverblik.dk/CustomerApi/index.html

However:

Assume you have the following C# prof of concept code:

```cs
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

var token = "eyJ...";
var client = new RestClient("https://api.eloverblik.dk") 
{
    Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(token)
};

/* Get power usage from June 1st 2022 until September 1st 2022 */
var request = new RestRequest("api/meterdata/getmeterreadings/2022-06-01/2022-09-01");
var response = await client.GetAsync(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

When I run the code I get an error code "BadRequest" when I try to call `await client.GetAsync`.

What am I doing wrong?

They write in the API that the token is formattet as `Bearer {token}`, but I thought that JwtAuthenticator did that for me?

Comment: Have you tried using something to intercept the request (e.g. Fiddler) to see the full HTTP request that is being sent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you call API incorrectly.

Check again documentation on API at https://api.eloverblik.dk/CustomerApi/index.html.

1. `getMeterReadings` is a POST method, not a GET (so, you need to call `client.PostAsync` and not `client.GetAsync`)
2. `getMeterReadings` expects also JSON-body to be sent (with list of metering points).

Also, I would recommend you to test your requests using some HTTP-request tool (i.e. Postman) and when you're pretty sure that request works move it into C#.

Comment: Duh! That is what I get when trying to do something when I am not quite awake. I about to go to work now, but I will test again when I get home.

Comment: Tried `Postman` with the get meteringpoints and even that one gave Bad Request, but at least it told why: `<h2>Our services aren't available right now</h2><p>We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.`